# (color online) label in RevTeX

Tags: floats, captions, revtex

For colored figures, Physical Review journals require that the caption label takes the form "FIG. 1 (color online). Caption content" if the figure will not appear in color in print.

Could someone with RevTex experience tell me how to put that "(color online)" label before the caption's label separator (i.e. before the period that follows the figure's number)?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your current setup? Not everyone is familiar with RevTeX's format and/or requirements. It'll speed up the process of getting solutions your way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `revtex4-1` there is a hook `\@caption@fignum@sep` for determining the separator following the float number, which defaults to a period followed by a space:

```
\def\@caption@fignum@sep{. }
```

You can define a new command `\colorcaption` to be used instead of `caption` for colored figures.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorcaption}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\@caption@fignum@sep}{ (color caption). }%
  \caption[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

This command redefines `\@caption@fignum@sep` to have the caption you want. `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` ensure that the change is made locally.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorcaption}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\@caption@fignum@sep}{ (color caption). }%
  \caption[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
\colorcaption{Colored figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Normal caption}
\end{figure}

\vspace*{\fill} % just for displaying purposes

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This does exactly what I need.  Apologies for not including the MWE.

Comment: @user82567 You're welcome. And don't mind for the MWE, in this case the question was clear enough even without it. But, generally consider adding a MWE to your questions ;-) Happy TeXing.